# Control speed in CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am newbie to iOS app development. I am using CABasicAnimation to draw a line horizontally across my app screen. I am successfully able to draw the line however I am not able to control the speed of animation.

Below is the code for drawing line.

```
-(void)drawLine{

    _boxPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [_boxPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0,60.0)];
    [_boxPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, 60.0)];



    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    layer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    layer.fillColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    layer.lineWidth = 5.0f;
    layer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    layer.path = _boxPath.CGPath;
    layer.speed = 3.0;


    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"line"];
    animation.duration = 3.0;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"line"];
}
```

No matter whatever values I change for layer speed and animation duration theres no change in animation speed. I want to slow the speed by which the line is drawn.

Any suggestions would be of great help

Comment: `speed = 3.0` would actually speed up the drawing (3 times normal).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is nonsense. Three points:

- If you're going to use implicit animation, you would use CATransaction `setAnimationDuration:` to set a longer duration.
- If you're going to use explicit animation, use it correctly. Creating a CABasicAnimation and just adding it does nothing; you need to configure it first. There is no "line" key path so your animation is meaningless.
- You cannot animate nothing. You have to animate *a change* in something. What you probably want to animate is a change in the `strokeEnd` from zero to one.